# Avoiding the Fibonacci numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

For given positive integers $a$ and $b$, let $(a,b)$ be "special" if
$an+b$ is not a Fibonacci number for every positive integer $n$.

For instance, $(8,4)$ and $(8,6)$ are special.

There are infinitely many special pairs since $(8k,4k)$ is special for every $k$. But these are a subsequence of the $(8,4)$ case, so I want to count them as the same case.

A special pair $(a,b)$ is called "maximal" if there is no other special pair $(c,d)$ such that $\{an+b\;|\; n \textrm{ is positive integer}\}$ is a subset of $\{cn+d\;|\; n \textrm{ is positive integer}\}$.

For instance, $(8,4)$ and $(8,6)$ are maximal while $(8,12)$ and $(16,8)$ are not.

My question : Are there infinitely many maximal special pairs?

Comment: Yes. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560570/do-fibonacci-numbers-form-a-complete-residue-system-in-every-modulus

Comment: @JoachimKönig Thank you!